# How to send to redirect to a user after creating a node and display a message?

Tags: rules, redirection, status-messages

I want to be able to re-direct a user after creating a node of a specific content type and then display a message.

How can I accomplish this? Is the best way by using rules modules or custom module ?

With a custom module, I do not know what hook I would have to use in order to trigger after content type is been publish.

I know that I can use the drupal_goto to redirect them + and used the  drupal_set_message to create a notification.

On the another hand, I know that using rules can be used to accomplish some of all this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules module can act on a "A new node has been created" event and has both "Page redirect" and "Display a message to a user" actions.

Answer (score 1):

If you use modules like Ubercart or Drupal Commerce, you already have Rules module enabled. 
I'm not personally a fan of Rules module due to difficulties in migrating content and because the module is heavy to accomplish a few tasks.

You have few hooks you can implement.

- [`hook_node_insert`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7)/[`update`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7)`: Executes on all node insert and update events, even the programmatic ones. Do **NOT** call drupal_goto() in such hook because it can break a lot of things and the remaining hooks will not run.
- [`hook_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7): Go for this! Better yet you can improve the number of hook calls if you implement `hook_form_node_form_alter` ([`hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7)). You can check the node type inside the hook. If you implement `hook_form_alter`, make sure you validate the `$form_id`.

While in the form alter hook, add your custom submit handler, which can then set the form redirect destination and display the message.

```
<?php

function MYMODULE_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Validate node type and other conditions here.
  $form['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_SOME_APPROPRIATE_FUNCTION_NAME';
}

function MYMODULE_SOME_APPROPRIATE_FUNCTION_NAME($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'somewhere/you/want/to/redirect';
  drupal_set_message(t('Some message you want to display'));
}
```